# Select2 jquery plugin - delete data from database

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I have jquery select2 input field:

[image]

when I click on "add" button I add this values to database.
But what when user click on "x" to change values:
[image]

then I need to update my database... but how? Is there some function that I can see where an values is deleted from input fields to can do some ajax to update my database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind a "change" event handler to the select2 element, just like you would for an ordinary select or input element. If an element was removed from the select2 control, the event object will have a "removed" property, which refers to the removed choice.

```
$('#select2Id').change(function(event) {
    if (event.removed) {
        alert(event.removed.id);
    }
});
```

UPDATE:

And as @gmaestro (the OP) points out in a comment below, you can bind a "select2-removed" event handler. That event is fired only when a choice is removed. In this case, the event object includes a "val" property, which refers to the id of the removed choice, and a "choice" property, which refers to the removed choice.

```
$('#select2Id').on('select2-removed', function(event) {
    alert(event.val);
});
```

[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W7urx/)

[Select2 Documentation](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

Comment: also this is no bad: .on("select2-removed", function(e) { log ("removed val="+ e.val+" choice="+ JSON.stringify(e.choice));})

Comment: @gmaestro - The [documenation](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) says the custom event property is named "object", not "choice", but it looks like the documentation is wrong, and you are correct.